# Post / store object containing data from angularjs to php page

Tags: php, angularjs

I am trying to post the data from angularjs controller to php page for payment gateway purpose. I am able to post all the contents as surl,furl,email... that all the mandatory fields. Beside this is am posting the an object as "totalorder" which consist of nested array and some other fields.

Here is my controller file

```
$http({
method: "post",
url: window.location.href + "postform.php",
data: {
    txnid:$scope.payment.txnid,
     amount:$scope.payment.amount=1,
     productinfo:$scope.payment.productinfo,
     firstname:$scope.payment.firstname,
     email:$scope.payment.email,
     phone:$scope.payment.phone,
     surl:$scope.payment.surl,
     furl:$scope.payment.furl,
    service_provider:$scope.payment.service_provider,
    totalorder:$scope.payment.totalorder,
    hash:$scope.payment.hash
    /*email: $scope.email,
    pass: $scope.password*/
},
headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
});
```

Its posting and while displaying that data in postform.php page shows me as [object object] in console as well as in webpage, but there values are not able to seen in console what they exist.

Here is my postform.php page

```
$email=$_POST['email'];
$txnid=$_POST['txnid'];
$firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$amount=$_POST['amount'];
$productinfo=$_POST['productinfo'];
$surl=$_POST['surl'];
$furl=$_POST['furl'];
$totalorder=$_POST['totalorder'];
$totallist=json_decode($totalorder);
echo ("'<script>console.log('$totalorder')</script>'");
```

Even i Tried to different ways to get those values as by storing the data in json_decode, direct access, foreach concept but all of them no use as all they show me [object object] but not their inner values.

As i am thinking that, my data is posting correctly. So, if any hint / other process  will help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Please inject "$httpParamSerializerJQLike" into your controller/service/factory, and use following code, then you are good to go.

```
$http({
method: "post",
url: "/postform.php",
data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike({
    txnid:$scope.payment.txnid,
     amount:$scope.payment.amount=1,
     productinfo:$scope.payment.productinfo,
     firstname:$scope.payment.firstname,
     email:$scope.payment.email,
     phone:$scope.payment.phone,
     surl:$scope.payment.surl,
     furl:$scope.payment.furl,
    service_provider:$scope.payment.service_provider,
    totalorder:$scope.payment.totalorder,
    hash:$scope.payment.hash
}),
headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
                        }
});
```

Comment: the url is not posting to that page, and even not showing me any error in console

Comment: i changed the url to "/postform.php", which i guess is your endpoint. if you  have more issue, you better provide a jsfiddle link.

Comment: its not navigating, from controller to php page.

Comment: endpoint means...? Here postform.php is my end point, and its not posting to that page